# How to store a numpy arrays in a column of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

Is it possible to store arbitrary `numpy` arrays as the values of a *single* column in a dataframe of `Pandas`?

The arrays are all 2-dimensional, and I intend to use them to calculate values for other columns in the same dataframe.

To provide some context of what I'm trying to do here:

Each array is an adjacency matrix of some network, and for each network I want to calculate its various characteristics (e.g. density, centralities, clustering coefficient, etc) which are in fact other columns in the same dataframe.

Comment: may be it's me, but I think that question is not clear enough

Comment: FWIW I don't think your intention sits well with your request.  While you can store arbitrary objects as values, you can't really do much with them in a vectorized fashion.

Comment: @DSM, the arrays are really just adjacency matrices of different graphs, and the other columns in the same dataframe are various network characteristics calculated based on each matrix. Do you suggest that I should decompose the matrix and store each row of the matrix in a separate column?

Comment: @RomanPekar, I've edited and provided more info in my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Store them as elements as you would do for any other data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
b = np.arange(10, 20).reshape(2,5)
pd.DataFrame({'foo':[42,51], 'arr':[a,b]})
Out[10]: 
                                            arr  foo
0            [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]   42
1  [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]   51
```

Note that what you try to do sounds more to use a [`Panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel).

Comment: Note, Panel is now deprecated.

Comment: This `df` can not be stored in PyTables format, `df.to_hdf('test.hdf', key='xxx', format='table')` will fail

Comment: @Boud by this way the numpy arrays get stored as a Series. Is there any way I can save it as `numpy.ndarray` in dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean store arbitrary numpy arrays as the values of a column in a dataframe of Pandas?

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


x = np.random.randn(50, 25)
random_frame = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

This will store the array x in a DataFrame where the column names are 0, 1, 2, 3...  Could you clarify?  I think this is more a comment, but I don't know if I can comment yet.

Comment: i want to store arrays as values of a *single* column inside a dataframe, if possible.

Comment: I'm guessing that the 2 dimensional is n x m, and not nx1 right?  I don't know if you can store an n x m array as a single column of a dataframe. Possible that I just haven't seen it.  Would love to see how though.