# putting matrix in one pandas DataFrame cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to take a list of 1000 np.ndarrays (each element in the list is an array whose shape is 3X3X8) and use this list as a pandas DataFrame column, so that each cell in the column is a matrix.
How can it be accomplished?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574258/how-to-store-a-numpy-arrays-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/why-xarray.html).

I've found this really useful for abstracting "square" data where all of the arrays in your list have the same shape.