# How to convert column value to array from csv python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, dataset

hallo sorry for my bad English, I want to convert my pixels column to separated numpy array for every row (if read using pandas dataframe it columns values will be read as array).
this is example of my dataset, I have tried split every row of pixels for every space, but because of the dataset is about 35.000 data and the pixels value are long, so the pandas going error

> target, pixels
>
> 0, 12 14 14 16 29 30 29 39 50 60 12 10 0 29 40 14
>
> 1, 13 15 15 17 25 32 23 31 59 62 17 19 1 22 20 20
>
> 2, 12 16 16 18 32 33 22 45 23 12 12 10 2 50 45 13

to
(if read by dataframe)

> target, pixels
>
> 0, array[12,14,14,16,29,29,39,50,60,12,10,0,29,40,14]
>
> 1, array[13,15,15,17,25,32,23,31,59,62,17,19,1,22,20,20]
>
> 2, array[12,16,16,18,32,33,22,45,23,12,12,10,2,50,45,13]

Comment: I'm not so clear about your question. You want every row as an separate array? like: array1: [12, 14, 14, ...], array2: [13, 15, 15,...], am I right?

Comment: yep you're right

Comment: what is the datatype of your pixel column?

Comment: @Adji I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574258/how-to-store-a-numpy-arrays-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe/19574528

Comment: @bumblebee it's a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There maybe other methods that is more memory efficient, but I came up with a simple solution like this:

```
l = [] # this will be a storage list for your array
for n, row in enumerate(df.index):
    df.iloc[row, :] = l[n]
```

Then you can access the separated array in the list l

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

Not very much clear on your question, but hope below suggestion will help,

Try to convert the column in matrix
--load it into a numpy array and reshape it so that it is in desired dimensional

I think for image pixle data, Digit Recognizer problem on MNIST data is very helpful
Give a look to kaggle kernal

[https://www.kaggle.com/aman9d/digit-recognizer-svm-88-3-data-visualization/data][1]

Comment: Thank you so much!!